# Reset boot-repair options

Tags: grubrescue

I have boot-repair installed and it was working fine until one day I checked the option "Purge GRUB before reinstalling it"  and went ahead and did what it said. But now, I tried to fix the GRUB and was off-line so I couldn't do it. Then I realized that the option "Purge GRUB before reinstalling it" is grayed, so I can't uncheck it. I purged boot-repair and reinstalled it but the problem continues. I've been thinking there's probably a configuration file I have to reset or delete so the option is available again.

Comment: Have you tried to boot from a boot-repair CD?

Comment: Yes, I have. And I successful reinstalled the GRUB, but the problem I described persists.

Comment: Here's my BootInfo URL http://paste.ubuntu.com/1053015/

Answer (score 0):

Boot-Repair's "Purge GRUB" option can't be unticked if some GRUB executables (eg grub-install) are missing in the system you want to repair.
The "Purge GRUB" option will download the GRUB packages from Internet and reinstall them.

If you need more information, please indicate your [BootInfo URL](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11136267&postcount=1).